# Getting "socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused" python paramiko

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, paramiko

Getting error connection refused error when trying to connect to the host to copy a local file to the host server. Don't have any issue connecting to the server remotely though.

```
host = "9.29.22.222"
 username = "XXX"
 password = "XXX"
 local_path = "/Users/samuelhii/Desktop/file.txt"
 remote_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\file.txt"
 s = paramiko.SSHClient() 
 s.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
 s.connect(host,22,username,password)
 sftp = s.open_sftp()
 sftp.put(local_path,remote_path)
```

Answer (score 5):

The connection was refused by the server. This can be caused by several reasons not related to Python programming:

- a firewall
- the SSH service is configure not to take requests from your IP
- bad host ip
- … (many more)

Check if you can use the normal SSH client to connect with this host/user/password combination.

Comment: The simplest explanation is that there's no service listening for connections on port 22 of the remote server. Ie, there's no SSH server running, or it's listening on a different port.