# ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am getting the following error message, when I try to execute the `Client.py` script using the command `Python3.7 Client.py`

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I tried to change the `gethostname` with `127.0.0.1`, but it did not work.

Bellow are my scripts for `Client.py` and `Server.py`

**Client.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((socket.gethostname(),1234))

msg = s.recv(1024)

print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

**Server.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))


s.listen(5)

while True:
   clientsocket,address = s.accept()

   print(f"Connection from {address} has been established")

   clientsocket.send(bytes("Hello","utf-8"))
```

Comment: Could you just try another port? Maybe another process is already using this port. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093568/getting-socket-error-errno-61-connection-refused-python-paramiko) Your code worked flawlessly here.

Comment: Im still receiving this error even if i change the port number

Comment: Try restarting your pc. Tried on my linux and windows, both worked.

Comment: let me try again

Comment: Just restarted my computer im still getting this error do i need switch 1234 port to something else

Comment: Well, if you still getting this error after changing the 1234 port and even restarting your pc, there must be something with your firewall or something like that. I don't think I can help too much.

Comment: weird its working now restarted my terminal on my mac and suddenly that fixed it

Comment: Cool! That must have been an open process.